# Is there any difference between "be hit with a ball" and "be hit by a ball"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Is there any difference between *be hit with a ball* and *be hit by a ball*? For example:

> One of the players was badly hit **with a ball**.
>
> One of the players was badly hit **by a ball**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The difference is very slight.

Hit **by a ball** indicates the ball colliding with the player. But it does not even imply that there was some entity that caused the ball to move at the player. **Hit by** is indicating that the hitting was done **by** the ball.

Hit **with a ball** indicates that there was some entity (presumably a wild pitcher) that did the hitting, and that a ball was used. But this other entity is implied. And not very strongly. It's like there is a very faint odor of pitcher nearby, but nothing specific.

In the **hit with** form, the **by** is implied. If it was the pitcher who did it, it could be rewritten as "the player was **hit with a ball by the pitcher**."

It's really not a very strong inference though. In other situations it might be erased entirely. **Hit by a string of bad luck** and **hit with a string of bad luck** are not really different at all. That is because we don't usually assume that bad luck can be imposed by somebody else.

Comment: If a ball was flying through the air, and it hit you, you were hit by a ball. If someone walks up to you with a ball in their hand, and hits you with their hand so that the ball strikes you, you were hit with a ball.